# Add checkbox to autocomplete vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

Currently working on autocomplete based on vanilla javascript. Some how I brought the autocomplete in working condition but I need to append with checkbox for the multiple selection in the autocomplete list the user has to select the check box then it will apply in the field For example if the User type IND in the text field the result will disaply as with the checkbox India and again if the user type ZIM with the checkbox Zimbawae in the text field.
Multiple selection

Here is the sample code

```
function init(){
    outp = document.getElementById("output");
    window.setInterval("lookAt()", 100);
    setVisible("hidden");
    document.onkeydown = keygetter; //needed for Opera...
    document.onkeyup = keyHandler;
}
```

The rest of the code is available in fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/wsLre0f7/)

Kindly guide me

Answer (score 0):

So you can use a comma ( , ) to separate your different items, then you can use

`var items = document.getElementsByName("text")[0].value.split(',')`

now in items you have an array of items, use your autocompleting functions on the last item of the array:

```
items[items.length-1]
```

it should do the trick